# How to temporarily mount a large object on the side of my house?

Tags: outdoor, mounting, siding

I have a large, wooden snowflake I made that I'd like to mount on the side of my house this winter, but I don't want to put nails into the siding. The snowflake is about 3' across and about 15 lbs.

In the searching I've done so far, I've found [siding clips](https://www.google.com/search?q=siding%20hooks), but these either seem to be for vinyl siding, or they don't really come out.

I also thought about hanging it from some rope anchored to the eave, but the eave isn't straight and it is quite windy here in the winter, which may cause it to swing/scratch the wall.

I briefly considered mounting it on a post with a base on the ground, but I think that would look weird.

---

**Edit:** I don't mean to make it sound like any of the above options are unacceptable, except using nails. I've just been thinking over my options for the last week or so and these are the ideas I've had and my initial concerns with them. If anyone has done something similar, or sees a way to improve one of these ideas, that would be great too. I'm kinda hoping someone has had experience with using siding clips on non-vinyl siding and knows of a good brand that could hold the snowflake and is removable.

---

Here is a picture of the snowflake and the wall I'd like to mount it to:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on the restrictions you've presented, your post idea isn't farfetched and I don't think it will look particularly unusual, especially if you consider to paint the post on which it is mounted to match the color of the siding. From any appreciable distance, the post will mostly vanish.

On close inspection, or a second look, the post may "pop into view," but the viewer will have already experienced the primary focus of the snowflake.

If the post idea is still rejected, the hanging idea could be better implemented by attaching it by cables to the eaves, but also attaching cables to the ground, to prevent movement. You could get away with a minimum of three cables, one above and two below, or two above and one below. A padded substance behind the snowflake will improve circumstances, as well. Use enough padding to push the cables all the tighter, forcing a more secure friction attachment to the wall. Paint the cables to match the siding?

Comment: I like the cable ides.  14-guage construction wire would work as well and for less cost.  The three point tie down also seems sound.  The one thing I see is that you may need a one or two foot long, 2"x2" stand off block secured directly to the middle of the back of the snow flake, to acquire the tension you need to maintain stability.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Hearing someone else say it, I think the post idea might work. Also, I didn't mean to be so down on the other ideas I mentioned. I haven't tried anything yet, I've just been thinking it through in my head so far. I could be mistaken about something, or just didn't think it all the way through (like the idea of adding some padding to the back if using cables). The only thing I've ruled out for now is no nails in the siding. :)

Comment: @PaulLogan or fred_dot_u: How would you suggest to attach the cables to the eave? I was thinking about using eye-hook screws going up into the bottom of the eave, is that what you'd suggest?

Comment: Screw eyes are better than screw hooks, although in your case, the tension on the cables will prevent hop-off at the hook.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a pair of sheet metal hooks that you can slide up under the siding and attach to the top edge of the board below. They'd basically be a strip of galvanized steel (one third of a 4x6 step flashing, for example), with one end bent over. Pound it nice and flat and flare the end slightly to act as a catch.

Slide them up behind the siding so they hook on the top of the board, then pull down slightly to secure. You could bend the bottom into a hook for wire attachment, or  you could punch a hole in the bottom end.

Once you're done with it, either pull it out forcefully or push it up behind the board above and forget it.

Some self-adhesive felt pads on the snowflake will protect your wall.

Comment: That's basically what I've seen for the siding clips, which was my first thought, but I'm a little worried about them being stuck up there (a little less worried if I could push them all the way up, if I couldn't get them out). I'm also a worried about putting too much weight on a piece of siding, but I suppose the force is perpendicular to the nails. I guess it just depends on how close the nails were put to the top of the board (they might pull through the top of the board).

Comment: Is it hardboard or cementboard? 15 lbs. spread across two hangers shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It is cementboard

Comment: Sorry, but just to clarify: Is there a difference between hardboard and cementboard, or are you thinking that if it was either of those it would be okay? Also, have you seen these types of clips at the hardware store before, or do you think I'd have to make some?

Comment: I think either would be ok, but cementboard is a bit less tolerant of bending. Be gentle. I've never seen them for sale, but I haven't looked.

Comment: A quick search returns [something like what I'm describing](https://www.homeproductsnmore.com/Vinyl_Siding_Hooks_Original_Pack_p/vsh05.htm). The top hook would need to be reversed from that in your case.